# Геолокация по IP адресу

Tags: php, ip, геолокация

Изучаю определение локации пользователя по IP-адресу.

Делаю такой код:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // узнаем IP посетителя
$data = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=' . $ip);
echo $data['country']; // Страна 
echo $data['city']; // Город 
echo $data['latitude']; // Широта 
echo $data['longitude']; // Долгота
```

В итоге мне выдает, как будто я нахожусь в Алма-Ата, Казахстан, хотя мое истинное местоположение в западной Сибири. Кто-нибудь тестировал сервис www.geobytes.com, насколько он достоверен и точен? Если с этим сервисом лучше не связываться, тогда скажите, какой лучше использовать, чтобы малой кровью решить эту проблему.

Comment: Идеального сервиса точного опредения местонахождения по ай-пи -- не существует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот сервис немного неправильно вычесляет местоположение, мне написал, что я нахожусь в Берне, Швейцария, а по факту в Украине, Запорожье.  )))
Вот вроде норм сервис http://ipgeobase.ru/cgi-bin/Software.cgi

http://ross.vc/?p=204 - а тут немного описывается, как и что.

Comment: Да спасибо, это что мне как раз надо). Все оформил в modx в виде своего сниппета, потому все работает замечательно.

Comment: Сайт переехал на адрес http://ross.pp.ru/?p=204